# How to pass function as EventCallback variable in Blazor component

Tags: event-handling, blazor

I have a component `MyComponentWithRenderFragments`, that renders a child component `MyNestedComponentOne`. I want the child to have an `EventCallback` that supplies some data back up to the page, but I can't figure out how to pass the function down to the child component.

Here's What I have:

Page:

```
@page "/"
@using BlazorAppPlayground.Client.Components

    <MyComponentWithRenderFragments
        SomeDataForComponent="Hello World"
        NestedComponentOneInfo='new MyNestedComponentOne(){ SomeDataForNestedOne="Testing", Callback = /* What goes here? */ }'> 
<!-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ -->
        <NestedComponentOneTemplate>
            <MyNestedComponentOne
                SomeDataForNestedOne="@context.SomeDataForNestedOne"
                Callback="@context.Callback">
            </MyNestedComponentOne>
        </NestedComponentOneTemplate>

    </MyComponentWithRenderFragments>


<!-- This VVV works fine, and is here for reference -->
    <BlazorAppPlayground.Client.Components.MyNestedComponentOne
        SomeDataForNestedOne="@callbackText"
        Callback="DoAThing"><!-- I know DoAThing is applicable, because it works here -->
    </BlazorAppPlayground.Client.Components.MyNestedComponentOne>

@code {
    private string callbackText = "Callback test";

    private async Task DoAThing(string data)
    {
        callbackText = data;
    }
}
```

MyComponentWithRenderFragments:

```
<h3>MyComponent => @SomeDataForComponent</h3>

@NestedComponentOneTemplate(NestedComponentOneInfo)

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string SomeDataForComponent { get; set; } = null!;

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment<MyNestedComponentOne> NestedComponentOneTemplate { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public MyNestedComponentOne NestedComponentOneInfo { get; set; }

}
```

and MyNestedComponentOne:

```
<h3>MyNestedComponentOne => @SomeDataForNestedOne</h3>
<button @onclick="@DoAThing">Do a Thing</button>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string SomeDataForNestedOne { get; set; } = null!;

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> Callback { get; set; }

    private async Task DoAThing()
    {
        await Callback.InvokeAsync("SomeDataToBePassedBack");
    }
}
```

I can't figure out how to pass the function to the `NestedComponentOneInfo` property of the outer component.

Note: I know based on this small example, I could just make `MyNestedComponentOne` a child of `MyComponentWithRenderFragments`, eliminating the template, and that would allow me to have the code similar to the code that works (below the code that does not in the `Page`). This is a dumbed-down set of components to illustrate the issue I'm facing. The actual components are significantly more complex.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `new MyNestedComponentOne()` is weird. Make it either an `Info` or a `Component`, it can't be both.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but you can't create an instance of a component and then try and pass it to the Render process.  That's what this is trying to do.

```cs
NestedComponentOneInfo='new MyNestedComponentOne(){ SomeDataForNestedOne="Testing", Callback = /* What goes here? */ }'>
```

The code below demonstrates how to use a `DynamicComponent` and also a cascaded value.

I'm guessing at your context.  If I've misunderstood, please provide more information on what you're trying to do in your question.

*MyNestedComponentOne*

```cs
<h3>MyNestedComponentOne => @SomeDataForNestedOne</h3>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@(() => this.OnButtonClicked("Hello"))">Say Hello</button>
<button class="btn btn-secondary" @onclick="@(() => this.OnButtonClicked("Goodbye"))">Say Goodbye</button>
<button class="btn btn-info" @onclick="@(() => this.OnButtonClicked(this.SomeDataForNestedOne))">Return Provided Data</button>

@code {
    [Parameter] public string SomeDataForNestedOne { get; set; } = null!;
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<string> Callback { get; set; }
    [CascadingParameter] private Func<string, Task>? CascadedCallback { get; set; }

    private async Task OnButtonClicked(string value)
    {
        if (CascadedCallback is not null)
            await CascadedCallback.Invoke(value);
        else
            await Callback.InvokeAsync(value);
    }
}
```

*MyComponentWithRenderFragments*

```cs
<h3>MyComponent => @SomeDataForComponent</h3>

<DynamicComponent Type=this.ComponentType Parameters=this.ComponentInfo />

@this.ChildContent

@code {
    [Parameter] public string SomeDataForComponent { get; set; } = null!;
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public Type? ComponentType { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public Dictionary<string, object>? ComponentInfo { get; set; }
}
```

*Index*

```cs
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.CompilerServices

<MyComponentWithRenderFragments ComponentType=typeof(MyNestedComponentOne) ComponentInfo=this.dynamicComponentParameters />

<MyComponentWithRenderFragments ComponentType=typeof(MyNestedComponentOne) ComponentInfo="@(new() {{ "SomeDataForNestedOne", "Hello Blazor"}})">
    <CascadingValue Value=this.DoAThing >
        <MyNestedComponentOne SomeDataForNestedOne="Call UK" />
        <MyNestedComponentOne SomeDataForNestedOne="Call France" />
        <MyNestedComponentOne SomeDataForNestedOne="Call Portugal" />
    </CascadingValue>
</MyComponentWithRenderFragments>


<div class="bg-dark text-white p-2 m-2">
    <pre>Value = @callbackText</pre>
</div>

@code {
    private string callbackText = "Callback test";

    private Dictionary<string, object> dynamicComponentParameters => new()
    {
        { "SomeDataForNestedOne", "Testing"},
        {"Callback", EventCallback.Factory.Create<String>(this, DoAThing)}
    };

    private async Task DoAThing(string data)
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
        callbackText = data;
    }
}
```